# Creación de base de datos, tablas PHP

Tags: php, mysql, css, tablas, backend

Tengo un proyecto escolar el cual consiste en crear una página de rifas de autos. La persona le daría click al btn de comprar, rellenaria un formulario con nombre, correo y luego pagaría. Al pagar, se le da un número de boleto MÁS un folio (un folio sería otro número al azar). Tienen que ser 60 mil boletos. Mi idea para la creación de la base de datos y tablas fue esta:

**Tablas:**

> usuarios: id(PK), nombre, correo

> boletos: id(PK), numero, usuario_id(FK)

> premios: id(PK), nombre, cantidad, boleto_id (FK)

> ganadores: id, boleto_id, premio_id, usuario_id

> compra: id, boleto_id(FK), ganador_id(FK)

Estaría bien? También estoy en duda de cómo podría crear los 60 mil boletos , si alguien puede guiarme un poco se lo agradecería

Comment: Por que tendiras que guardar lo numeros de voleto ?  van del 0 al 60,000 son constantes

Comment: y que es lo que has realizado de codigo

Comment: Guardar los números así tengo un registro en la base de datos no? O como sería?

Comment: tienes las tablas creadas de mysql?

Comment: No, justamente no las cree porque no estoy seguro de si estoy en lo correcto. Pero tengo una idea de cómo hacerlas, las publiqué a ver qué opinaban

Comment: yo creo que si estas en lo correcto

Comment: Bueno lo haré de esa forma, y como harían para colocar los 60k de boletos? Creo que eso es lo que más me preocupa xD

Comment: pues yo lo haria con un bucle for el cual que no pare hasta llegar los 60k boletos

Comment: Ahh gracias. Mi idea era desde php mediante ese bucle crear los números y hacerle  un insert a la tabla boletos, la columna números. Estaría bien? xD

Comment: si eso si estaría bien

Comment: tambien los campos id puede ponerlo auto incremental y deja hacer la magia xD

Comment: Vale, es que me gustaría que cada id represente un número de boleto , creo que for loop es, gracias por la idea

Comment: de nada y si tienes mas ayuda ya sabes donde estoy y si puede acepta la edición :)